Определить старшие разряды числа и вычислить из сумму, не используя циклы и строки
Необходимо определить старшие разряды введенного числа и вычислить их сумму без использования циклов и строк.
моя попытка:
a = int(input("Введите число: "))
count = len(str(a))
n = count // 2
if count == 4:
    one = a // 1000
    two = (a // 100) % 10
    sum = one + two
elif count == 3:
    one = a // 100
    two = (a // 10) % 10
    sum = one + two
elif count == 2:
    one = a // 10
    sum = one
print(f"Сумма элементов старших разрядов: {n}")


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

str(number)[index]

@u111 "не используя ... строки"

я голосую за переоткрытие вопроса из-за интересного ответа с итератором.

Я тоже.........

dl = 10**int((x.bit_length() - 1)*math.nextafter(math.log10(2), 0)) выдаёт хорошее приближение dl <= x and x < 100*dl для всего диапазона целых чисел Python используемого практически 10...10**9999999 и более. Далее потребуется только один условный оператор. Или, как вариант, можно анализировать несколько старших бит числа (надо думать и, наверное, окажется медленнее).

Если можно функции, то есть рекурсивное решение. high_sum – просто обёртка. Вся работа делается внутри rec. Параметр n скачет по числу через два разряда, m перебирает все разряды. s накапливает сумму. На каждой итерации к s прибавляются две цифры (n % 10 + n // 10 % 10) и вычитается одна (m % 10).
Множитель n // 10 and 1 равен нулю если мы добрались до старшего разряда в n и количество разрядов нечётно. В противном случае он равен единице. Он нужен чтобы при нечётном числе разрядов средний разряд включался в сумму.
n or ... выполняет ... если n равно нулю.
n and ... выполняет ... если n не равно нулю.
def high_sum(n):

    def rec(n, m, s):
        n or print(s)
        n and rec(
            n // 100,
            m // 10,
            s + n % 10 + n // 10 % 10 - (m % 10) * (n // 10 and 1)
        )

    rec(n, n, 0)


high_sum(int(input()))


$ echo 1234 | py temp.py
3

$ echo 12345 | py temp.py
6

$ echo 123456 | py temp.py
6


P.S. От некрасивого множителя n // 10 and 1 можно избавиться предварительно умножив n на десять:
def high_sum(n):

    def rec(n, m, s):
        n or print(s)
        n and rec(n // 100, m // 10, s + n % 10 + n // 10 % 10 - m % 10)

    rec(10 * n, 10 * n, 0)


high_sum(int(input()))


Не помешает rec(abs(n), abs(n), 0). С отрицательными числами алгоритм уходит в бесконечность.

Или так: rec(m := abs(n), m, 0)  Чтобы дважды не вызывать abs и не повторяться

Если задуматься, то задача не так уж проста. Привожу вариант на итераторе (который не попал в список запрещенных), без циклов (под циклами я понимаю for и while), без конвертации в строку и без условных операторов (if и match). Но так или иначе без прохода по числу не обойтись, что и делает итератор. Существует вариант с использованием log10, но тогда, во-первых, придется импортировать библиотеку math, во-вторых, появляются нюансы с числами кратными 10.
Предложенный алгоритм задействует особенность функции iter вызывать некую функцию до тех пор, пока не будет получено триггерное значение (в данном случае кортеж (0,0)). Функция get_digits сохраняет свое состояние между вызовами в собственном атрибуте 'num', дабы хранить остаток от деления на 10 исходного числа.
Алгоритму не важен размер заданного числа.
num = 12345
# Функция раскладывает число на цифры
# Как только цифры закончатся, вернет (0,0)
def get_digits():
    get_digits.num = getattr(get_digits,'num',(abs(num),0))
    get_digits.num = divmod(get_digits.num[0], 10)
    return get_digits.num
# Итератор вызывает функцию до тех пор, пока не получит (0,0)
digits = (*iter(get_digits, (0,0)),)[::-1]
# Оставляем только остаток от деления
digits=tuple(map(lambda item: item[1], digits))
# Как альтернатива, можно получить digits одной строкой
# digits = tuple(map(lambda item: item[1],(*iter(get_digits, (0,0)),)[::-1]))
# Вычисляем количество старших разрядов
idx = len(digits) // 2 + len(digits) % 2
print(f"Сумма элементов старших разрядов: {sum(digits[:idx])}")


Интересное использование iter. Здорово!

Вы используете функции. Если функции разрешены, то можно сделать рекурсию, без *, которая на деле маскирует цикл.

Очень круто и неожиданно!

Рекурсию очень не люблю. Угроза переполнения стека. Возможно это мои личные предрассудки.

@VladimirBogdanov Смотря какой уровень глубины возможен. Ну и можно переписать рекурсию на цикл при желании.

@CrazyElf, переписать можно, но потребуется останавливать цикл без использования условий.

get_digits получилась одноразовая.

Господа, по заданию циклы в явном виде использовать нельзя. Да и if для остановки рекурсии тоже нельзя. Кроме того, используя рекурсию, принципиально ничего не добьемся, кроме излишнего потребления памяти в виде хранения в стеке всех состояний вызова рекурсивной функции, пропорционально количеству цифр в заданном числе. Станислав верно подметил, что * маскирует цикл. Так и рекурсия тоже маскирует цикл. Как я указал в преамбуле к ответу, без прохода по цифрам числа не обойтись, а это есть цикл.

Одноразовость get_digits нивелируется просто. Обертываем весь код внешним def-ом и вызываем этот внешний def многократно. При этом get_digits становится внутренней функцией, потребляемой однократно при каждом вызове внешнего def-а.

рекурсия тоже маскирует цикл - не соглашусь. Рекурсия (возможность рекурсивного исполнения функций) более базовый/простой/элементарный/фундаментальный механизм. Цикл требует меняющего значения переменных (присвоения значения переменной), рекурсия может быть выражена без присваиваний. Грубо говоря, язык рекурсивных функций требует меньше базовых понятий чтобы описать вычисление, но сам при этом более выразителен, чем язык циклов.
